# How to develop an Outlook/Mail Plugin?

Tags: email, outlook, plugins

I want to develop a plug-in that does this:

*A button, when clicked, opens the new mail window but has a certain phrase in the subject line, for e.g. when I click a button called 'PROJ123', the new mail window opens with the subject line "[PROJ123]"*

Other functionality it would need:

- Ability to Create/Update/Delete Buttons as needed

What is the best way to do this?

Any and all tips, references, online resources, examples are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 25):

To create a plugin for Outlook, I'd read these resources:

- [CodeProject: How to Create Plugin for Outlook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1112815/How-to-Create-an-Add-in-for-Microsoft-Outlook)
- MSDN: [How to Create Plugin in .NET](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/0fb13e44-b360-4251-a7eb-45c266e40a9b/)
- Using [VSTO for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905533.aspx) to create plugins in Outlook

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I found an add-in that may be useful to you:

- A [template plugin](http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-addins/quick-templates-for-outlook.html) for Outlook

Answer (score 4):

You can use VBA and a UserForm, or a Custom Menu. Here is an example of the code:

```
Private Sub cmdCommand_Click()
    Dim eml As MailItem

    Set eml = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    eml.Subject = "Proj1"
    UserForm1.Hide
    eml.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't test this, but it concise enough!

Answer (score 4):

This is not about creating a button, it answers the headline: How to develop an Outlook/Mail Plugin?

Here is a walkthrough that I followed to developed my first Add-In in 10 minutes.

["Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx)

Main steps:

- Creating an Outlook VSTO Add-in project for Outlook.
- Writing code that uses the object model of Outlook to add text to the subject and body of a new mail message.
- Building and running the project to test
  it.

Comment: This does not create a button.

Comment: The title is How to develop an Outlook/Mail Plugin? and I reached here expecting to learn how to develop a plugin. The rest of the answers did not explain this.